# Replace a tree node in a matched location of a binary tree

Tags: prolog

How to replace a matched node in a binary tree with prolog? Properties of tree: it is not a binary search tree, but every element is unique, so replace operation will effect one element in tree at maximum.

initial tree definition:

```
tree('Q',
     tree('P',
          tree('R',
               empty,
               empty),
          tree('S',
               empty,
               empty)), 
     tree('T',
          empty,
          empty))
```

Let's say new node to replace node 'R' with tree('new', tree('child1', empty, empty), tree('child2', empty, empty))
expected result:

```
tree('Q',
     tree('P',
          tree(tree('new',
               tree('child1',
                    empty,
                    empty), 
               tree('child2',
                    empty,
                    empty)),
          tree('S',
                empty,
                empty)
               )),
     tree('T',
          empty,
          empty))
```

Current status of the code:

```
:- dynamic([tree/1]).

run:-
 retractall(tree(_)),
 assertz(tree(tree('Q', tree('P', tree('R', empty, empty), tree('S', empty, empty)), tree('T', empty, empty)))),
 retract(tree(T)),
 insert('newElement', T, NewTree),
 assertz(tree(NewTree)),
 tree(T),write(T),!.


insert(NewItem,empty,tree(NewItem,empty,empty)):- !.

insert(NewItem,tree(Element,Left,Right),tree(Element,NewLeft,Right)):-
   true, %match function needs to be here
   !,insert(NewItem,Left,NewLeft).

insert(NewItem,tree(Element,Left,Right),tree(Element,Left,NewRight)):-
    insert(NewItem,Right,NewRight).
```

Comment: Can it happen that you replace an element with another element that happen to be in the tree already, thus making the elements non-unique?

Comment: No, this will all be handled before using replace command, and user will be notified not to add a same entity, or entity will be tagged with a prefix to ensure consistency and uniqueness @Boris.

Comment: The tree that you expect to get as a result in your example is not a well formed tree. You should try to fix that, otherwise it is unclear how a replace should work. Or do you really mean that a node can be a tree itself? If so, keep in mind that a traversal would not traverse the tree contained in it.

Comment: Ah yes in the second one i guess, i wrote it for making it readable. tree('new', 'child1', 'child2') must be written as tree('new', tree('child1', empty, empty), tree('child2', empty, empty)) @boris.

Comment: Edit your question! You can also try to indent the tree and split it across multiple lines, to make it easier to read.

Comment: Fixed indentation.. @boris

Comment: See the edit I made for what a proper identation might look like. You will also notice, with the help of the proper identation, that you second tree is still not well formed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've changed a bit the syntax of your tree, since it was too much verbose for my taste.
Maybe you could consider using a supported tree format, like XML (coded as element/3),
that would give you much power in pattern matching, via library(xpath). Anyway

```
replace_tree(Old, New, Old, New).

replace_tree(Old, New, t(Key, L, R), t(Key, L1, R1)) :-
    replace_tree(Old, New, L, L1),
    replace_tree(Old, New, R, R1).

% base case of the recursive data structure
replace_tree(_Old, _New, t, t).
```

yields

```
?- T=t(1, t(2, t(3, t(4, t, t), t(5, t, t)), t(6, t, t(3,t,t))),t), replace_tree(t(3,X,Y),t(new,X,Y),T,O).
T = t(1, t(2, t(3, t(4, t, t), t(5, t, t)), t(6, t, t(3, t, t))), t),
X = t(4, t, t),
Y = t(5, t, t),
O = t(1, t(2, t(new, t(4, t, t), t(5, t, t)), t(6, t, t(3, t, t))), t) ;
T = t(1, t(2, t(3, t(4, t, t), t(5, t, t)), t(6, t, t(3, t, t))), t),
X = Y, Y = t,
O = t(1, t(2, t(3, t(4, t, t), t(5, t, t)), t(6, t, t(new, t, t))), t) ;
T = O, O = t(1, t(2, t(3, t(4, t, t), t(5, t, t)), t(6, t, t(3, t, t))), t) ;
false.
```

Comment: It works! but why does it produce different solutions for T? how can i cut it to one solution? It includes the solution O==T but we don't want that do we?

Comment: @GökhanYu: I have keept the code to a minimum, so you can attempt to tailor it at your wisdom... play with cuts, to remove unwanted solutions - if you think it's better.. otherwise, play with findall/setof to enjoy Prolog aggregation via backtracking...

Answer (score 1):

Saving to a file and reading from a file.... If you have a Prolog term, you can read it from a file and write it to a file using ISO Prolog `read_term` and `write_term`.

In a file 't.txt' you can have:

```
tree(b, tree(a, empty, empty), tree(c, empty, empty)).
```

and then, from the top level:

```
?- open('t.txt', read, File), read_term(File, Tree, []), close(File).
File = <stream>(0x1a38450),
Tree = tree(b, tree(a, empty, empty), tree(c, empty, empty)).
```

So this is all in the manual of your Prolog implementation. I am using SWI-Prolog for demonstrating.

Then, is your tree organized in any particular way? It doesn't say, but assuming it is a binary search tree, in file `tree.pl`:

```
% insert(T0, E, T1)
% Adding E to the binary search tree T0 results in T1.
insert(empty, E, tree(E, empty, empty)).
insert(tree(X, Left, Right), E, tree(X, Left1, Right)) :-
    E @< X,
    insert(Left, E, Left1).
insert(tree(X, Left, Right), E, tree(X, Left, Right1)) :-
    E @> X,
    insert(Right, E, Right1).
```

Then,

```
?- [tree].
true.

?- open('t.txt', read, File),
   read_term(File, Tree, []),
   insert(Tree, x, T1),
   close(File).
File = <stream>(0x1a20e80),
Tree = tree(b, tree(a, empty, empty), tree(c, empty, empty)),
T1 = tree(b, tree(a, empty, empty), tree(c, empty, tree(x, empty, empty))).
```

... and so on.

Comment: That is great, i will switch code working with terms, but how can i replace the node, which is my original question? (thank you for your answer)

Comment: @GökhanYu It is right there, in the `insert/3` predicate. You should read it through again, and look at the last query in my answer.

Comment: Oh my bad, but my tree is not a binary search tree, so i need to search for all occurrences of a node and replace them with a new tree. (as in my example)

Comment: @GökhanYu But is it really so that your tree is not ordered in any way and you have to traverse it completely to know if the element you are replacing is in the tree or not?

Comment: Sad but exactly a full traversal is needed @Boris, it's a decision tree.

Comment: @GökhanYu Do you realize that your predicate `replace` would have to have 4 arguments: `replace(T0, Old, New, T1)`? Or are you supposed to pass it a predicate which will succeed if the node should be replaced and fail otherwise?

Comment: Where does this "decision tree" come from? The point being, just because it is a decision tree does not mean that it is arbitrary.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time @Boris. Replace with 4 arguments, i'm aware, will hopefully work as i wanted. I don't need to pass to a predicate.


It's a decision tree, which can be extended by user's questions and answers, and can be saved to file.

It's arbitrary because there is no metric to find where a node is, but tree will be extended as user traverse it.

Comment: @GökhanYu But then, are you going to replace any subtree that holds a certain element, or only replace the element leaving the children (and replacing any occurences of the element within the children)? And is replacing an atomic operation, or can it happen that nodes of the tree can change before they have been reached? Can you have elements occurring more than once? It is difficult to come up with a solution when the problem is not well defined. I suggest you edit the original question to add all relevant information from our discussion in the comments here.

Comment: Every element is unique @Boris.. I will edit my question. But that is all info anybody needs.

Comment: @GökhanYu You cannot have a correct solution if your problem statement is not complete.